# iOS8 UILabel dynamic width with constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on an app, where I am currently stuck on using autolayout on my UICollectionViewCell. Inside the cell there is one UILabel and two UIImages. I want the images to stick to the right hand side of the cell, next to each other, and the label stick to the left. The width of the label should expand depending on the space provided by the device, but it should end before the left of two images.

Here is the current setup of my UICollectionViewCell in Storyboard:
[image]

I hope that my description is not too complicated. I am looking forward to a solution either in Storyboard or in code, doesn't matter for me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want these constraints:

```
Container -> Label: = 20
Label -> Left Image: > 20
Left Image -> Right Image: = 20
Right Image -> Container = 20
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer - I am new to iOS development and was not aware of that you can add constraints with "greater than..." or "less than...".

Comment: There's a whole slew of constraint operations, I'd really recommend reading the reference docs on [auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1)